# Implementing a LinkedHashTable in C# with given Table C#

Tags: c#, interface, linked-list, hashtable

For an assignment for school I have to create a LinkedHashTable in C#. The teacher has given me a Table interface that I must go by, but I'm a little lost as to whether or not I'm making a HashTable/Dictionary in my LinkedHashTable class as if it was a data member and doing whatever management to make it linked.
What I had originally did was make a:

```
Dictionary<Key, List<Value>> hash;
```

in the LinkedHashTable class I made and the get, put, and contains methods I implemented pertained to that structure. Here is the table interface:

```
interface Table<Key, Value> : IEnumerable<Key>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Add a new entry in the hash table. If an entry with the
    /// given key already exists, it is replaced without error.
    /// put() always succeeds.
    /// (Details left to implementing classes.)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="k">the key for the new or existing entry</param>
    /// <param name="v">the (new) value for the key</param>
    void Put(Key k, Value v);

    /// <summary>
    /// Does an entry with the given key exist?
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="k">the key being sought</param>
    /// <returns>true iff the key exists in the table</returns>
    bool Contains(Key k);

    /// <summary>
    /// Fetch the value associated with the given key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="k">The key to be looked up in the table</param>
    /// <returns>the value associated with the given key</returns>
    /// <exception cref="NonExistentKey">if Contains(key) is false</exception>
    Value Get(Key k);
}
```

In the test file, he's got stuff like:

```
ht.Put("Chris", "Swiss");
try
{

foreach (String first in ht)
{
     Console.WriteLine("5");
     Console.WriteLine(first + " -> " + ht.Get(first));
}
```

The whole foreach loop makes me think that I'm supposed to implement my class in a way such that it is a LinkedHashTable in itsself, not just some class having a HashTable as a member. Unfortunately, I'm pretty confused as to how to do this. Any suggestions would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some reading on interface might help answer your question. Some class that you create may need to implement the given interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx